# Is it possible to recover a NTFS partition after it was formatted to NTFS using Gparted Live CD?

Tags: data-recovery, formatting, gparted, hard-drive-recovery, partition-recovery

I had a NTFS partition on my ASUS laptop that had Windows 7 on it.
I formatted it using Gparted Live CD because I thought there are some problems in Windows but then found out it was a problem of hardware...
Now I would want to recover the partition and use the old Windows 7 that I had on it...
Is it possible? :-)

Now I have 2 partitions on my laptop harddrive. 1st partition - NTFS that is empty (the one that I formatted) and has 200 GB and the 2nd partition - NTFS that has data on it and has 300 GB...

It was most probably a quick format since it took only like 1-2 seconds to format the partition... I didn't change the size of the partition or moved or resized other partitions on the harddrive...

I would want to "travel in time" and recover the partition, so that I would not have to install Windows 7 from scratch...

Comment: it's possible, but this post miss so many information, your current partition table estructure, and what you did before, and you want to recover tha partition? or data???, improve your question..

Comment: OK, I edited my question...

Comment: [Here](http://superuser.com/questions/221230/is-is-possible-to-restore-the-mft-of-a-ntfs-partition-after-a-format?rq=1) are some options to recover the partition you removed.

Answer (score 2):

As long as your second partition was always there and not created overlapping your deleted first partition it should be recoverable.  You can use a linux live CD and install testdisk to recover it. Here is a step by step guide:

http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/15761/recover-data-like-a-forensics-expert-using-an-ubuntu-live-cd/

1. Boot any linux live CD, e.g. Ubuntu
2. Install testdisk.  On ubuntu:  sudo apt-get install testdisk
3. Run testdisk as root:  sudo testdisk
4. Choose to create a new log file
5. Select your disk, e.g. /dev/sda  Choose Proceed
6. Choose the partition table type (likely Intel in this case)
7. Choose Analyze
8. Choose Quick Search
9. Select the deleted partition. You can use the left and right arrows to change its type (primary, logical, extended).  You can use T to change the partition type if needed.
10. Hit Enter then choose Write
11. Reboot

Comment: Although this may answer the question, you should give a more detailed description of the linked content and explain how it relates to the question. This will help ensure that this answer remains useful in the event the linked page is removed or goes offline. For more information, see [this Meta Stack Exchange post](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259).

Comment: I added the steps to recover a deleted partition