# Is it possible to recover a truncated file by changing its length?

Tags: linux, backup, data-recovery, fat32

I used `dd` to make a backup of an SD card, and went on to run `chkdsk` on it. Of course, `chkdsk` ended up removing all folders and moving all files to `FOUND.000` and `FOUND.001`, renaming them to `FILExxx.CHK` to make it even harder to figure out what kind of file it is.

Thankfully, I have a backup! Or so I thought, until I pressed the up arrow and the enter key in quick succession - my keyboard actually registered *two* presses of the up arrow (it does this occasionally, but up until now I didn't want to replace it just because of this), and so I ended up running the "backup" command again. I quickly cancelled it, but `dd` still truncated the file from its original ~60GB to a few MB. To prevent further damage, I immediately remounted the backup drive as read-only.

Can I recover the "full length backup" somehow? Will setting the file size to the full size of the card using a tool like `fallocate` or something similar work? Do I have to look through all 15000 `*.CHK` files by myself?

The filesystem on the card was FAT32, in case that helps. The backup file itself was stored on a drive formatted with NTFS.

Comment: Whats important is the filesystem which holds your backup file.

Comment: @grawity: Sorry, forgot to mention it. It's NTFS because I need to access it from Windows, too. Just added it to the question.

Comment: I would be shocked if it worked.  The problem is not that the file was truncated, but that new data was written to the file.

Answer (score 1):

Using DD  might work, but most likely won't.   The difficulty is fragmentation - DD won't know how the underlying blocks the file used are linked.

You are getting into the area of $$$ experts here, so depending on the value of the data it might make sense to go to a data recovery expert, but assuming thats not on the cards -

I would be inclined to make a bit copy of the drive, and try recovery on that.  You might be able to recover a fair chunk of the filesystem by using a mirror of the MFT. Although the answer to a different question - have a look at [Is is possible to restore the MFT of a NTFS partition after a format?](https://superuser.com/questions/221230/is-is-possible-to-restore-the-mft-of-a-ntfs-partition-after-a-format#221247) - as the steps you might want to take could be substantially similar.

Comment: “using a mirror of the MFT” The $MFTMirr file is actually not a mirror of the MFT. Also, this is not a problem of recovering a broken MFT, because OP overwrote the specific entry related to the DD image.